# How to hide a specific page instead all pages from search

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to hide a few pages from WordPress Search results. For that, I have written a code.

```
function jp_search_filter( $query ) {
  if ( ! $query->is_admin && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 10,11,20,105 ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'jp_search_filter' );
```

However, this code doesn't seem to be working. The pages that I wanted to hide from WordPress search results are still showing. What I have done in the above code is I passed the page IDs as an array.

Can anyone help me with the code? Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you verified your if condition is actually fulfilled? (Can a query be the search query and the main query at the same time in WP?)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am needing to do the same.